# Shutil.move() function moved files into a folder which i cant open

Tags: python, python-3.x, shutil

I used `shutil.move()` function to move some important files into desirable directory. The directory did not exist, So i gave the name as a parameter i `shutil.move()` function.  After the execution, it moved the files in a dir(Which does not seem to be a dir, when seeing properties it says its a "File") which i cannot open. can you please help me to open this file to extract my files??
The code was like this:

```
for file in Path("C/Users/Mahum/Downloads").glob(*.exe):
    shutil.move(file, "E/New Folder")
```

The code executed with zero exit code but i got that problem.....

Comment: Try add a `/` in the end of "E/New Folder/", without it, "New Folder became a file, not a folder.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But as i have done (the mistake), my question was how to recover those file which BECAME a "file"....'???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have misunderstood what shutil can do.

- If the destination is a dir, then it will move the source file into
  that dir.
- However if the destination doesnt exist, it will rename the src as
  the destination.
- If the destination does exist and its a file it will overwrite that
  dest file with the source file.

So in you case lets say you had 5 files. "E/New Folder" didnt exist. So on the file loop

file1 is renamed as E/New Folder (at this point file1 doesnt exist and its contents are in E/New Folder)

file2 overwrites E/New Folder (file2 is removed and E/New Folder now has the contents of file2 and file1 contents are lost completely now)

file3 overwrites E/New Folder (file3 is removed and E/New Folder now has the contents of file3 and file2 contents are lost completely now)

file4 overwrites E/New Folder (file4 is removed and E/New Folder now has the contents of file4 and file3 contents are lost completely now)

file5 overwrites E/New Folder (file5 is removed and E/New Folder now has the contents of file5 and file4 contents are lost completely now)

So chances are E/New Folder is indeed a file and will hold the contents of the list file that went through shutil.move to this destination and all other files and contents are lost.

Comment: Thanks for your quick and valuable reply..I think the same happened as you explained...

Answer (score 0):

Your path should be `C:/Users/Mahum/Downloads` instead of `C/Users/Mahum/Downloads`

Comment: That's not the problem actually..I did the same as you've told.Its just the typing mistake in the question. My problem is that it was done correctly but rather in a dir it moved those files in a single file, which i am having problem opening

Answer (score 0):

If you didn't create the new folder before you moved the files it may have treated the request as a file and overwritten ontop of each other. Another thing that may have ocurred it just overwitten ontop of each file. If you didn't have a back up you may have lost the files. You can try to recover with a disk recovery program. Look for one for OS.

Comment: Was writting when Chris Doyle responded. Cheers